# Parsing Pysnmp with regex

Tags: python, regex, pysnmp, python-webbrowser

I need to parse the Pysnmp output. I want to run the script from web browser. So the code is as follow:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print '<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'
print '<title>Interface searcher</title><p>'

import re

from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('blablablabla'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('x.x.x.x', 161)),
    'iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2',
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                for line in val:
                    if re.search("(xe|ae)[^.]*$", line):
                       print line

print "</p></body></html>"
```

It does not produce output if run this script from web browser.

If I change the last loop to:

```
else:
    for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
        for name, val in varBindTableRow:
            print(val)
```

It produces output on web browser as follow:

```
fxp0 lsi dsc lo0 tap gre ipip pime pimd mtun fxp0.0 lo0.0 em0 em0.0 lo0.16384 lo0.16385 em1 em1.0 cbp0 demux0 irb pip0 pp0 ae0 ae1 ae2 ae3 ae1.0 ae2.109 ae2.110 lsi.0 ae2.196 ae2.234 ae2.236 ae2.311 ae2.313 ae2.314 lsi.1 ae2.452 ae2.507 ae2.557 ae2.649 ae2.735 ae2.803 ae2.804 ae2.977 ae2.1097 ae2.1108 ae2.1194 ae2.1197 ae1 ae2.1306 ae2.1328 ae2.1435 ae2.1463 ae2 ae2.1503 ae2.1596 ae2.2020 ae2.2345 ae2.2465 ae2.32767 ae3.0 ae2.1801 ae2.1446 ae2.2420 ae2.2421 ae2.2422 lc-4/0/0 lc-4/0/0.32769 lc-4/1/0 lc-4/1/0.32769 lc-4/2/0 lc-4/2/0.32769 lc-4/3/0 lc-4/3/0.32769 pfh-4/0/0 pfh-4/0/0.16383 pfe-4/0/0 pfe-4/0/0.16383 pfe-4/1/0 pfe-4/1/0.16383 pfe-4/2/0 pfe-4/2/0.16383 pfe-4/3/0 pfe-4/3/0.16383 lc-5/0/0 lc-5/0/0.32769 lc-5/1/0 lc-5/1/0.32769 lc-5/2/0 lc-5/2/0.32769 lc-5/3/0 lc-5/3/0.32769 pfh-5/0/0 pfh-5/0/0.16383 pfe-5/0/0 pfe-5/0/0.16383 pfe-5/1/0 pfe-5/1/0.16383 pfe-5/2/0 pfe-5/2/0.16383 pfe-5/3/0 pfe-5/3/0.16383 xe-5/0/0 xe-5/0/1 xe-5/0/2 xe-5/0/3 lsi.1048838 xe-5/0/3.0 xe-5/1/0 xe-5/1/1 xe-5/1/2 xe-5/1/3 xe-5/2/0 xe-5/2/1 xe-5/2/2 xe-5/2/3 xe-5/3/0 xe-5/3/1 xe-5/3/2 xe-5/3/3 xe-5/3/3.0 xe-4/0/0 xe-4/0/1 xe-4/0/0.32767 xe-4/0/2 xe-4/0/3 lsi.1048839 xe-4/0/0.2465 lsi.1048840 xe-4/0/0.2422 xe-4/0/0.2421 xe-4/0/0.2420 xe-4/0/0.2345 xe-4/0/0.2020 xe-4/0/0.1801 xe-4/0/0.1596 xe-4/0/0.1503 xe-4/0/0.1463 xe-4/0/0.1446 xe-4/0/0.1435 xe-4/0/0.1328 xe-4/0/0.1306 xe-4/0/0.1293 xe-4/0/0.1197 xe-4/0/0.1194 xe-4/0/0.1108 xe-4/0/0 lsi.1048841
```

but if I run my script from within shell it prints out line by line as follow:

```
xe-4/1/3.3219
xe-4/2/1.1304
xe-4/2/1.250
gr-5/0/0.11
ae2
ae2.3461
xe-4/0/0.3462
xe-4/0/0.3461
xe-4/0/1
xe-4/0/1.3461
xe-4/0/2.3462
xe-4/0/2.3461
xe-4/0/3.3462
xe-4/0/3.3461
xe-4/2/1.1514
xe-4/2/1.1634
```

I want my script to get the data from my device which is working fine but I want to parse the output with regex so that it prints out on web browser all interfaces without dot, for example the ones - *ae2, xe-4/0/0* and prints every interface line by line as follow:

```
ae2
xe-4/0/0
etc.
```

I have checked my regex at regexr.com and it matches the lines I want. Please see it in action http://regexr.com/3agof
Any input will be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if re.search("(xe|ae)[^.]*$", line):
    print line.split('.')[0] + "\n"
```

That should do it for you in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that regexp engine does not match pysnmp values because what pysnmp returns in var-binds is not a plain Python string. Rather it is a  pyasn1 object which may sometimes be safely str()'ed into Python string, but not always.

To get all original SNMP octet-string data (typed "str" in Python 2 or "bytes" in Python 3) you could use OctetString.asOctets() method (e.g. line.asOctets()). This only makes sense for OctetString values, not Integers or other SNMP types.